# Automatic table from list

Tags: tables, macros

it is possible to create a table from a list? I mean something like:

Ex1 (each three elements generate a new column):

```
\peopleA{P. Smith, A. Row, B. Streams, O. Green, L. Handley}
\peopleB{A. Hause, J. Ring}
\peopletable
```

[image]

Ex2:

```
\peopleA{P. Smith, A. Row, B. Streams}
\peopleB{A. Hause, J. Ring}
\peopletable
```

[image]

Ex3 (if list empty just generate one empty column):

```
\peopleA{}
\peopleB{}
\peopletable
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In short, yes it is possible, but please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example showing what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An approach using [`xinttools`](http://WWW.ctan.org/pkg/xint).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hscale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\newcommand{\peopleA}[1]{%
   % first we trim leading and trailing spaces from each item
   % #1 maybe a macro, it will be expanded; this means first item
   % will be expanded. Prefix this item with a space is this is to
   % be avoided
   \oodef\peopleAlist{\xintCSVtoList{#1}}%
   % now build an array for easy access
   \xintAssignArray\peopleAlist\to\peopleAarray
}%

\newcommand{\peopleB}[1]{%
   \oodef\peopleBlist{\xintCSVtoList{#1}}%
   \xintAssignArray\peopleBlist\to\peopleBarray
}%

\newcommand{\peopletable}{%
   % say we have Na people of type A and Nb people of type B
   % I think from the OP, it is asked to always use three rows
   % from 0 to 3 people of given type, 1 column
   % from 4 to 6 people, 2 columns
   % from 7 to 9 people, 3 columns
   % We do the arithmetic in TeX, not using packages
   \begingroup
     \count0 \peopleAarray{0}
     \advance\count0 by 2
     \divide \count0 by 3
     \ifnum\count0=0 \advance\count0 by 1 \fi
   \edef\peopletableNbOfColsA{\the\count0}%
     \count2 \peopleBarray{0}
     \advance\count2 by 2
     \divide \count2 by 3
     \ifnum\count2=0 \advance\count2 by 1 \fi
   \edef\peopletableNbOfColsB{\the\count2}%
     \count4 = \count0
     \advance\count4 by \count2
   \edef\peopletableNbOfCols{\the\count4}%
   %\show\peopletableNbOfCols
   \edef\peopletableColIndices{\xintSeq{1}{\peopletableNbOfCols}}%
   %\show\peopletableColIndices
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{|*{\peopletableNbOfCols}{l|}}%
     \hline
     \multicolumn{\peopletableNbOfCols}{|c|}{\textbf{Title}}\\
     \hline
     \multicolumn{\peopletableNbOfColsA}{|l|}{PeopleA}&
     \multicolumn{\peopletableNbOfColsB}{l|}{PeopleB}\\
     \hline
     % first row
     \xintFor* ##1 in {\peopletableColIndices}:
     {\xintifForFirst{}{&}%
      \ifnum##1>\peopletableNbOfColsA\space
         \unless\ifnum\numexpr3*(##1-\peopletableNbOfColsA)-2>\peopleBarray{0}
         % unfortunately xinttools create arrays checking
         % "index-out-of-range" type of errors, instead
         % of silently expanding to nothing, hence the check above
           \peopleBarray{3*(##1-\peopletableNbOfColsA)-2}%
         \fi
      \else
         \unless\ifnum\numexpr3*##1-2>\peopleAarray{0}
           \peopleAarray{3*##1-2}%
         \fi
      \fi
     }\\
     \hline
     % second row
     \xintFor* ##1 in {\peopletableColIndices}:
     {\xintifForFirst{}{&}%
      \ifnum##1>\peopletableNbOfColsA\space
         \unless\ifnum\numexpr3*(##1-\peopletableNbOfColsA)-1>\peopleBarray{0}
         % unfortunately xinttools create arrays checking
         % "index-out-of-range" type of errors, instead
         % of silently expanding to nothing, hence the check above
           \peopleBarray{3*(##1-\peopletableNbOfColsA)-1}%
         \fi
      \else
         \unless\ifnum\numexpr3*##1-1>\peopleAarray{0}
           \peopleAarray{3*##1-1}%
         \fi
      \fi
      }\\
      \hline
     % third row
     \xintFor* ##1 in {\peopletableColIndices}:
     {\xintifForFirst{}{&}%
      \ifnum##1>\peopletableNbOfColsA\space
         \unless\ifnum\numexpr3*(##1-\peopletableNbOfColsA)>\peopleBarray{0}
         % unfortunately xinttools create arrays checking
         % "index-out-of-range" type of errors, instead
         % of silently expanding to nothing, hence the check above
           \peopleBarray{3*(##1-\peopletableNbOfColsA)}%
         \fi
      \else
         \unless\ifnum\numexpr3*##1>\peopleAarray{0}
           \peopleAarray{3*##1}%
         \fi
      \fi
      }\\
      \hline
   \end{tabular}%
   \par
   \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\peopleA{P. Smith, A. Row, B. Streams, O. Green, L. Handley}
\peopleB{A. Hause, J. Ring}
\peopletable

\bigskip
With only three rows we soon get wide tables, so let's use digits for
demonstration purposes:


\peopleA{P. Smith, A. Row, B. Streams, O. Green, L. Handley,
  6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}

\peopleB{A. Hause, J. Ring, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

\peopletable
\end{document}
```

[image]

(works fine with empty columns)

---

OP asked for table taking up full textwidth, it can be achieved with `tabularx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\newcommand{\peopleA}[1]{%
   % first we trim leading and trailing spaces from each item
   % #1 maybe a macro, it will be expanded; this means first item
   % will be expanded. Prefix this item with a space is this is to
   % be avoided
   \oodef\peopleAlist{\xintCSVtoList{#1}}%
   % now build an array for easy access
   \xintAssignArray\peopleAlist\to\peopleAarray
}%

\newcommand{\peopleB}[1]{%
   \oodef\peopleBlist{\xintCSVtoList{#1}}%
   \xintAssignArray\peopleBlist\to\peopleBarray
}%

\newcommand{\peopletable}{%
   % say we have Na people of type A and Nb people of type B
   % I think from the OP, it is asked to always use three rows
   % from 0 to 3 people of given type, 1 column
   % from 4 to 6 people, 2 columns
   % from 7 to 9 people, 3 columns
   % We do the arithmetic in TeX, not using packages
   \begingroup
     \count0 \peopleAarray{0}
     \advance\count0 by 2
     \divide \count0 by 3
     \ifnum\count0=0 \advance\count0 by 1 \fi
   \edef\peopletableNbOfColsA{\the\count0}%
     \count2 \peopleBarray{0}
     \advance\count2 by 2
     \divide \count2 by 3
     \ifnum\count2=0 \advance\count2 by 1 \fi
   \edef\peopletableNbOfColsB{\the\count2}%
     \count4 = \count0
     \advance\count4 by \count2
   \edef\peopletableNbOfCols{\the\count4}%
   %\show\peopletableNbOfCols
   \edef\peopletableColIndices{\xintSeq{1}{\peopletableNbOfCols}}%
   %\show\peopletableColIndices
   \noindent
   \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{\peopletableNbOfCols}{X|}}%
     \hline
     \multicolumn{\peopletableNbOfCols}{|c|}{\textbf{Title}}\\
     \hline
     \multicolumn{\peopletableNbOfColsA}{|l|}{PeopleA}&
     \multicolumn{\peopletableNbOfColsB}{l|}{PeopleB}\\
     \hline
     % first row
     \xintFor* ##1 in {\peopletableColIndices}:
     {\xintifForFirst{}{&}%
      \ifnum##1>\peopletableNbOfColsA\space
         \unless\ifnum\numexpr3*(##1-\peopletableNbOfColsA)-2>\peopleBarray{0}
         % unfortunately xinttools create arrays checking
         % "index-out-of-range" type of errors, instead
         % of silently expanding to nothing, hence the check above
           \peopleBarray{3*(##1-\peopletableNbOfColsA)-2}%
         \fi
      \else
         \unless\ifnum\numexpr3*##1-2>\peopleAarray{0}
           \peopleAarray{3*##1-2}%
         \fi
      \fi
     }\\
     \hline
     % second row
     \xintFor* ##1 in {\peopletableColIndices}:
     {\xintifForFirst{}{&}%
      \ifnum##1>\peopletableNbOfColsA\space
         \unless\ifnum\numexpr3*(##1-\peopletableNbOfColsA)-1>\peopleBarray{0}
         % unfortunately xinttools create arrays checking
         % "index-out-of-range" type of errors, instead
         % of silently expanding to nothing, hence the check above
           \peopleBarray{3*(##1-\peopletableNbOfColsA)-1}%
         \fi
      \else
         \unless\ifnum\numexpr3*##1-1>\peopleAarray{0}
           \peopleAarray{3*##1-1}%
         \fi
      \fi
      }\\
      \hline
     % third row
     \xintFor* ##1 in {\peopletableColIndices}:
     {\xintifForFirst{}{&}%
      \ifnum##1>\peopletableNbOfColsA\space
         \unless\ifnum\numexpr3*(##1-\peopletableNbOfColsA)>\peopleBarray{0}
         % unfortunately xinttools create arrays checking
         % "index-out-of-range" type of errors, instead
         % of silently expanding to nothing, hence the check above
           \peopleBarray{3*(##1-\peopletableNbOfColsA)}%
         \fi
      \else
         \unless\ifnum\numexpr3*##1>\peopleAarray{0}
           \peopleAarray{3*##1}%
         \fi
      \fi
      }\\
      \hline
   \end{tabularx}%
   \par
   \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\peopleA{P. Smith, A. Row, B. Streams, O. Green, L. Handley}
\peopleB{A. Hause, J. Ring}
\peopletable

\bigskip
With only three rows we soon get wide tables, so let's use digits for
demonstration purposes:


\peopleA{P. Smith, A. Row, B. Streams, O. Green, L. Handley,
  6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}

\peopleB{A. Hause, J. Ring, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

\peopletable

\bigskip

\peopleA{}
\peopleB{}

\peopletable
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you!! and I forgot to add in the question that the tables should have always paper width. Could you recommend some literature for learning that kind of things in LATEX? I just know the bases

Comment: updated to get full-width tables. As to using LaTeX, the standard references, although dated, are the book of Lamport on one side, and the Companion by Mittelbach et al. Regarding my answer it uses `xinttools` which is a more recent package. Other more traditional methods do exist for building up tables in advance (rather than on-the-fly like here with `\xintFor`) and I guess you can see a lot on this site. Newer methods use the programming layer of LaTeX3 which is powerful and has useful data structures. But first get familiar in the Companion with the traditional packages.

Comment: I am afraid my answer to get fully understood requires you to read some relevant parts of the `xinttools` chapter in the `xint` documentation. This may not be best way to learn LaTeX, do start with more traditional sources first.